# Weekday Calculator Logical Error - Java

Tags: java, methods

I am a beginner that has been practicing Java on my own. I have just learned how to return values from methods. I attempted this exercise that can be found here  [Weekday Calculator](https://programmingbydoing.com/a/weekday-calculator.html).

I have working code that took me a while to write. (#proudNOOB)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WeekdayCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int yearsSince1900, total, remainder;

        System.out.print("Enter your year of birth ~ ");
        int year = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the month you were born in " + year + " ~ ");
        int month = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the day you were born in " + monthName(month) + " ~ ");
        int day = keyboard.nextInt();

        yearsSince1900 = year - 1900;
        // System.out.println(yy);

        total = (yearsSince1900 / 4) + yearsSince1900 + day + monthOffset(month);
        if ((isLeap(year) == true) && month == 1 || month == 2) {
            total = total - 1;
        }
        // System.out.println(total);

        remainder = total % 7;
        // System.out.println(remainder);

        // Display (day of week, month, day, year)
        System.out.println("\nYou were born on " + weekdayName(remainder) + ", " + monthName(month) + " " + day + ", " + year + ".");
    }

    public static int monthOffset(int month) {
        int offset;

        if (month == 1) {
            offset = 1;
        } 
        else if (month == 2) {
            offset = 4;
        } 
        else if (month == 3) {
            offset = 4;
        } 
        else if (month == 4) {
            offset = 0;
        } 
        else if (month == 5) {
            offset = 2;
        } 
        else if (month == 6) {
            offset = 5;
        } 
        else if (month == 7) {
            offset = 0;
        } 
        else if (month == 8) {
            offset = 3;
        } 
        else if (month == 9) {
            offset = 6;
        } 
        else if (month == 10) {
            offset = 1;
        } 
        else if (month == 11) {
            offset = 4;
        } 
        else if (month == 12) {
            offset = 6;
        } 
        else {
            offset = -1;
        }

        return offset;
    }

    public static boolean isLeap(int year) {
        boolean leap;

        if (year % 400 == 0) {
            leap = true;
        } 
        else if (year % 100 == 0) {
            leap = false;
        } 
        else if (year % 4 == 0) {
            leap = true;
        } 
        else {
            leap = false;
        }

        return leap;
    }

    public static String weekdayName(int remainder) {
        String weekdayWord = "";

        if (remainder == 1) {
            weekdayWord = "Sunday";
        } 
        else if (remainder == 2) {
            weekdayWord = "Monday";
        } 
        else if (remainder == 3) {
            weekdayWord = "Tuesday";
        } 
        else if (remainder == 4) {
            weekdayWord = "Wednesday";
        } 
        else if (remainder == 5) {
            weekdayWord = "Thursday";
        } 
        else if (remainder == 6) {
            weekdayWord = "Friday";
        } 
        else if (remainder == 7) {
            weekdayWord = "Saturday";
        }

        return weekdayWord;
    }

    public static String monthName(int month) {
        String monthWord = "";

        if (month == 1) {
            monthWord = "January";
        } 
        else if (month == 2) {
            monthWord = "February";
        } 
        else if (month == 3) {
            monthWord = "March";
        } 
        else if (month == 4) {
            monthWord = "April";
        } 
        else if (month == 5) {
            monthWord = "May";
        } 
        else if (month == 6) {
            monthWord = "June";
        } 
        else if (month == 7) {
            monthWord = "July";
        } 
        else if (month == 8) {
            monthWord = "August";
        } 
        else if (month == 9) {
            monthWord = "September";
        } 
        else if (month == 10) {
            monthWord = "October";
        } 
        else if (month == 11) {
            monthWord = "November";
        } 
        else if (month == 12) {
            monthWord = "December";
        } 
        else {
            monthWord = "error";
        }

        return monthWord;
    }
}
```

I tested my program with the automatic tests found in the exercise instructions. The program works against all those tests except 2 13 1977 which gives me output "You were born on , February 13, 1977" and it also works against my birthdate, amongst other random dates. However, I tried my dad's birthdate (just for the heck of it) and the output is faulty just as it was for the test case (the weekday name is missing).

INPUT:

Enter your year of birth ~ 1962

Enter the month you were born in 1962 ~ 12

Enter the day you were born in December ~ 29

OUTPUT:

You were born on , December 29, 1962.

I understand that according to my input and the program's logic, the yearsSince1900 variable has a value of 62. Then the total variable holds ((62 / 4) + 62 + 29 + 6) which equals 112. Then 112 % 7 equals 16, meaning that the remainder equals 0. Therefore, the weekdayName method returns no weekdayWord, since there is no condition where remainder == 0. What's the best way to fix this logical bug that messes up certain birthdates. I want this program to work for my dad's birthdate (and any birthdate proceeding 1900) as well so I can show it off to him. :D Also, any tips on self-learning programming and where to find simple games or exercises like this one would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you need additional information, please let me know.

Comment: You could also implement `weekday` with `return new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy").format(new Date(yyyy - 1900, mm, dd));`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this bug can be fixed by changing the Saturday remainder to zero since your method didn't account for a modulus of 0.

```
else if (remainder == 0) {
    weekdayWord = "Saturday";
}
```

Comment: Using `remainder == 0` should be enough here since the expression `remainder = total % 7` should evaluate to a number between 0 and 6.

Comment: Wait...now I'm entering my birthdate (year = 1995, month = 2, day = 4) and the output is off by a day...it should be Saturday but it shows Friday.

Comment: @camelCoder What apicellaj said does make sense. I think there is something going on with the logic you have implemented that needs rework.

Comment: I'm mistaken. Now some cases are off by 1 day...not sure how to fix this.

Comment: @camelCoder There is a separate logical error in your code. Since the day of the week is calculated using the value `total` you might want to look there.

Comment: I figured it out. :D if ((isLeap(year) == true) && (month == 1 || month == 2)) {
   total = total - 1;
  } I needed parantheses around "month == 1 || month == 2"

Comment: The condition for leap year had flawed logic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to every person that guided me in debugging my logical errors.

First of all, if the remainder equals 0 and the remainder equals 7, the weekdayWord should be set to "Saturday"

```
else if (remainder == 7 || remainder == 0) {
        weekdayWord = "Saturday";
    }
```

Secondly, my condition for the leap year checking, which would affect the total, and ultimately the weekdayWord, was flawed as a result of missing parentheses. The correct condition is:

```
if ((isLeap(year) == true) && (month == 1 || month == 2)) {
        total = total - 1;
    }
```

The program now successfully works for all cases I have tried. Time to show this off to my dad. :P